# Show changes git checkout makes to the working directory

Tags: git

How can I show the files git checkout adds/modifies/deletes in my working directory when I switch branches?

Comment: so depressing seeing a question nearly a decade old and there's still no good solution. i just want to know if package.json was modified so i know if i need to run npm install again :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any "verbose"-like option you can add to the `git checkout <branch>` command to output this information.  However, after the successful checkout, you can run:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD@{1} HEAD
```

The output from that command will indicate by the letter in the first column whether the file was deleted (`D`), added (`A`), modified (`M`), etc. with respect to the previous commit you were at.

As a possibly helpful additional point, note that when you switch branches, git will attempt to preserve local modifications to your files that haven't yet been committed.  If this switch of branch wouldn't clobber those changes, they will be indicated immediately on the terminal immediately after the checkout such as:

```
$ git checkout other-branch
M foo.c
M foo.h
```

Comment: Note that with `git diff --exit-status` you can make it exit with a non-0 (1) exit code, so you can perform some command if there were changes: `git diff --exit-code --name-status HEAD@{1} HEAD && echo no changes || echo things have changed`. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/bash-run-command2-if-command1-fails

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
git diff --name-status <branch_switching_to>
```

to see the difference before checking out and see what the checkout will modify.